# Induction proof of the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^na_i-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{a_i}\ge n(\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^na_i}-\frac1{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^na_i}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, inequality, induction, jensen-inequality

> Prove the following inequality:
> $$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i - \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{a_i} \geq n\left(\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^na_i}- \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^na_i}}\right)$$
> Where all the variables are greater or equal than $1$.

This inequality is a generalization of a standard one (actually the base case in the induction method I'm trying to use, as presented later on the post). I am thinking at the special type of induction called Cauchy Induction. Here is my progress:

**Base case**. It's a well known that, for $x, y \geq 1$:
$$x + y - \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y} \geq \sqrt{xy} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{xy}}$$

In fact, we can rewrite the form as:
$$(xy - 1)\left(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}\right)^2$$

**Inductive step 1** Prove that $p(n) \to p(2n)$. Let's consider $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$, $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n$ $2n$ numbers. From $p(n)$, we have that:
$$LHS \geq n\left(\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^na_i}- \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^na_i}}\right) + n\left(\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^nb_i}- \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i = 1}^nb_i}}\right)$$

And, by using the base case:
$$LHS \geq 2n \left(\sqrt[2n]{\prod_{i = 1}^na_ib_i}- \frac{1}{\sqrt[2n]{\prod_{i = 1}^na_ib_i}}\right)$$

However, I could not prove backwards induction step. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: At a quick glance, backwards-forward induction likely isn't easy to apply, because of how complicated the expression is relative to the terms, so we can't hope for an easy cancellation. Do you have reason to believe it's reasonably doable?

Comment: (In your induction step 1, note the final expression should be the $2n-$th roots.)

Comment: @MathStackExchange  Without induction you don't want? Without induction it's really obvious by Jensen

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Of course I'll accept any other solutions. However, I'd prefer induction, and especially Cauchy induction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proof without induction.

Let $a_i=e^{x_i}$ and $f(x)=e^x-\frac{1}{e^x}.$

Thus, since $x_i\geq0$ and $f''(x)=e^x-\frac{1}{e^x}\geq0$ for $x\geq0$,

we obtain that $f$ is a convex function on $[0,+\infty).$

Thus, by Jensen we obtain:
$$\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\geq nf\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}{n}\right),$$ which is your inequality